# Case insensitive regex in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to extract a query string from my URL using JavaScript, and I want to do a case insensitive comparison for the query string name. Here is what I am doing:

```
var results = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
if (!results) { return 0; }
return results[1] || 0;
```

But the above code does a case sensitive search. I tried `/<regex>/i` but it did not help. Any idea how can that be achieved?

Comment: That literal format **/regex/i** should work, unless you tried to concatenate it or something...

Answer (score 247, accepted):

You can add 'i' modifier that means "ignore case"

```
var results = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)', 'i').exec(window.location.href);
```

Comment: Any way I make that into one string?

Comment: @CardinalSystem `/abc/i`

Answer (score 51):

modifiers are given as the second parameter:

```
new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)', "i")
```

Comment: or `new RegExp('^' + string + '$', "i")`

Answer (score 9):

Simple one liner. 
In the example below it replaces every vowel with an X.

```
function replaceWithRegex(str, regex, replaceWith) {
  return str.replace(regex, replaceWith);
}

replaceWithRegex('HEllo there', /[aeiou]/gi, 'X'); //"HXllX thXrX"
```

Comment: Technically five lines, but who's counting 

Comment: Good point. I should study less coding and more math.

Answer (score 7):

For example to search word **date**, upper or lowercase you need to add param **i**

i = means incasesensitive

example

```
const value = "some text with dAtE";
/date/i.test(value)
```

or

```
const value = "some text with dAtE";
 new RegExp("/date/","i");
```

Answer (score 4):

Just an alternative suggestion: when you find yourself reaching for "case insensitive regex", you can usually accomplish the same by just manipulating the case of the strings you are comparing:

```js
const foo = 'HellO, WoRlD!';
const isFoo = 'hello, world!';
return foo.toLowerCase() === isFoo.toLowerCase();
```

I would also call this easier to read and grok the author's intent!

Comment: plus 1 for making me smile :D