# Case insensitive in regex with Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Case insensitive regex in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939715/case-insensitive-regex-in-javascript)

Right now I have this:

```
my_list.match(new RegExp("(?:^|,)"+my_name+"(?:,|$)")))
```

Which, given the following:

```
my_list = "dog, cat, boy"
my_name = "dog"
```

Would return true.

However if I have

```
my_list = "Dog,Cat,boy"
```

and

```
my_name = "boy"
```

The regex wouldn't match.  How would I adapt in order to be able to match with case insensitive?

Answer (score 1):

First off: Never build a regular expression from an unescaped variable. Use this function to escape all special characters first:

```
RegExp.quote = function(str) {
  return str.replace(/[.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-]/g, "\\$&");
};
```

It modifies the `RegExp` object, you need to include it just once. Now:

```
function stringContains(str, token) {
  var 
    spaces = /^\s+|\s+$/g,              // matches leading/trailing space
    token = token.replace(spaces, ""),  // trim the token
    re = new RegExp("(?:^|,)\\s*" + RegExp.quote(token) + "\\s*(?:,|$)", "i");

  return re.test(str);
}

alert( stringContains("dog, cat, boy", " Dog ") );
```

Note

- The `"i"` that makes the `new RegExp` case-insenstive.
- The two added `\s*` that allow white-space before/after the comma.
- The fact that `"(?:^|,)\\s*"` is correct, not `"(?:^|,)\s*""` (in a JS string all backslashes need to be escaped).