# Javascript Matching - case-insensitive

Tags: javascript, matching, case-insensitive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Case insensitive regex in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939715/case-insensitive-regex-in-javascript)

Values could be:

```
- Mike liam

- Joe mike

- Mondal mike effron
```

I want to mach every value contains 'mike' - case-insensitive

So, I tried:

```
var x = "mike";
if(valeu.match(new RegExp(x, "g"))
alert('success');
```

but that didn't work. any ideas ?

Answer (score 6):

You want the `i` flag (for "insensitive"):

```
if(valeu.match(new RegExp(x, "ig"))
                         -----^-----
```