# Javascript regx check the case insensitive

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a javascript regular expression and want to check the case insensitive for the below,

1) *My requirement is not to allow these two words(case insensitive) in a string.*

```
^(?!.*pmca|.*co40)\b.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]*$
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Case insensitive regex in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939715/case-insensitive-regex-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue by using the below code,

```
/^(?!.*pmca|.*co40)\b.[a-z0-9-.]*$/i
```