# mvc4 regularexpression to validate email

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to validate the email entered by user. I want to validate if email contains `gmail,yahoo,hotmail,rediffmail` then it is not allowed user to enter this email.

I tried following **Regex**

```
^([\w-\.]+@(?!gmail)(?!yahoo)(?!hotmail)(?!outlook)(?!rediffmail)([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,6})?$
```

It validates if there is `gmail or yahoo or hotmail` in email. But if user enter `someone@Gmail.com or someone@gMaIl.com` then it is allowing user even if it is wrong. I want to check it with ignore case sensitive.

Here I want to ignore case sensitive. I checked this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
but I am not getting where can I put **?i** in above expression. I want to validate it at client side. I am using this expression in MVC Model.

```
[RegularExpression(@"^([\w-\.]+@(?!gmail)(?!yahoo)(?!hotmail)(?!outlook)(?!rediffmail)([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid email")]
```

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937174/how-can-i-ignore-case-in-a-regularexpression

Comment: Sine JS does not support inline modifiers, use character classes: `var regex = new Regex(@"(?i)^([\w.-]+@(?![Gg][Mm][Aa][Ii][Ll])(?![Yy][Aa][Hh][Oo][Oo])(?![Hh][Oo][Tt][Mm][Aa][Ii][Ll])(?![Oo][Uu][Tt][Ll][Oo][Oo][Kk])(?![Rr][Ee][Dd][Ii][Ff][Ff][Mm][Aa][Ii][Ll])([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,6})?$");`.

Answer (score 0):

You can write this way:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(?!hotmail|gmail|yahoo)(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$
```

Comment: I tried your expression. But it is still allowing case sensitive `gMail` or `Yahoo` or `HOTMAIL` or 'GmAiL' which I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

You should put it right in front of expression

```
^(?i)([\w-\.]+@(?!gmail)(?!yahoo)(?!hotmail)(?!outlook)(?!rediffmail)([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,6})?$
```

I think js regular expression ignore case differentlely than .NET regex ((?i) vs /i).
Given regex will work fine on server side but an excepyion will be thrown on client side.

Here is a workaround

```
^([\w-\.]+@(?!(g|G)(m|M)(a|A)(i|I)(l|L))(?!(y|Y)(a|A)(h|H)(o|O)((o|O)))(?!(h|H)(o|O)(t|T)(m|M)(a|A)(i|I)(l|L))(?!(o|O)(u|U)(t|T)(l|L)(o|O)(o|O)(k|K))(?!(r|R)(e|E)(d|D)(i|I)(f|F)(f|F)(m|M)(a|A)(i|I)(l|L))([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,6})?$
```

Allthough it is ugly, but hopefully will work on both sides.

Comment: it is js that throws exception, try given workaround.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach to using Regex, which can get long and ugly for this use case, is to create a custom `ValidationAttribute`.

```
public class WorkEmailAddressAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        string[] personalEmailDomains = new string[] { "@gmail.com", "@yahoo.com", "@hotmail.com", "@outlook.com" };
        string valueString = value.ToString();

        foreach (string personalEmailDomain in personalEmailDomains)
        {
            if (valueString.Contains(personalEmailDomain))
            {
                return new ValidationResult(this.FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```