# Why is this Regex not working on MVC unobtrusive validator?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, regex

I have the folowing regex on my MVC view model
(p.s. all other regex`es work fine)

```
[Required, MaxLength(256)]
[RegularExpression(@"/(\[Brand name\])/i", ErrorMessage = "Reply message <strong> Must</strong> contain <strong>[Brand name]</strong>")]
public string ReplyMessage { get; set; }
```

[image]

Comment: .NET regex pattern strings do not require (and must not have) regex delimiters. So instead of: `@"/(\[Brand name\])/i"` use: `@"(?i)(\[Brand name\])"`.

Comment: @ridgerunner Actually, that should be an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the need, the regex should be:

```
.*(\[Brand name\]).*
```

Or in other words, any character before and after, but must contain "[Brand name]".

Comment: OK, seems to be working, but wont accept any options.. If I add it like this "/.*(\[Brand name\]).*/i" doesn't

Comment: @Marty, you don't technically need the ending wildcard, try removing it and see what happens.

Comment: @Marty Does .NET allow you to create your regex using `//` delimiters ?!!

Comment: @Sniffer, those Regex's are used in JavaScript.

Comment: I think this is C# he is using.

Comment: @Sniffer, those Regex's are applied in JavaScript by the MVC framework.

Comment: I tried this approach, but it didn't help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4218836/regularexpressionattribute-how-to-make-it-not-case-sensitive-for-client-side-v