# MVC4 Class Data Annotations - How to check that field does not equal a given string?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Hopefully that title made sense. Essentially I want to set up validation using Data Annotations in a class that will fail if one the fields (call it Field1 for example) equals a given string (i.e. "abc").

For example

```
public class myClass
{
    [Required]
    public string Filed1 {get;set;}    //*** I want validation to fail if this string equals "abc"
}
```

Hope that all makes sense. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `RegularExpression` attribute for this:

```
[RegularExpression("^(?!abc$).*$")]
```

The regex is a negative lookahead (basically checking that string does not start with `abc` followed by string end), and then allowing any other sequence.

Comment: Be aware that `RegularExpressionAttribute` is case sensitive. This will still allow ABC, Abc, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I thought RegularExpression might be the way to go but I'm useless at writing them.

Comment: Extending `public class MyValidation : ValidationAttribute { ... }` is another way to go. A benefit of the regex attribute is it will also validate client side if you are sticking with Microsoft's guidance.

Comment: An example of creating your own validation attribute and integrating with the client side validation can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4218836/regularexpressionattribute-how-to-make-it-not-case-sensitive-for-client-side-v/14962296#14962296