# Regex to Allow 1st letter of a string only Alphabet in C#

Tags: c#

I have a case where i need to allow Alphanumeric but 1st letter of the string should always be Alphabet only

Below is sample case

```
string text1 = "A1222"; Valid
string text2 = "1A22"; // Invalid
```

Comment: Why would you need regex for this?

Comment: Please show us the code for your latest attempt and where you got stuck, so that we can tailor the answer to be most helpful and educational for you.

Comment: `^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d]*$`

Comment: `IsLetter()` Does not work or you just havent tried anything and want us to do this for you?

Comment: @Josip i need in Data Annotation for Model validation

Comment: @ZahidMustafa what?

Comment: ^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d]*$ 
this is what i needed Thanks

Comment: Related answer you might find useful [RegularExpressionAttribute - How to make it not case sensitive for client side validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4218836/regularexpressionattribute-how-to-make-it-not-case-sensitive-for-client-side-v). Since you question does not mention Data Annotation I am linking it into the comments only ;-)

Answer (score 1):

A variant of what was already said in the comments would be

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"^[a-z][a-z\d]*$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

That one is not particularly complex, but for complex ones it is very nice making them case insensitive.

Warning: Do note that `[A-z]` would yield wrong results as mentioned in this related question [Difference between regex [A-z] and [a-zA-Z]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923380/difference-between-regex-a-z-and-a-za-z)