# Have HTML5's a inputs pattern attribute ignore case

Tags: regex, html, input

I need to have HTML's input elements pattern ignore the case of the value,
like have if the regex is /[a-z]*/ could I get it to match all uppercase letters too?
(I know I could just do /[a-zA-Z]*/, but that was an example.)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I don't think it is possible.

1. The  specification on `<input pattern>` [[1](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-pattern-attribute),[2](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-pattern-attribute)] specifies that

   - the pattern uses the ECMAScript (i.e. Javascript) flavor of regex
   - it is compiled "with the global, ignoreCase, and multiline flags ***disabled***"
2. In Javascript, the only way to make a regex ignore case is to set the modifier externally (`/.../i`). The PCRE syntax `(?i)` is not supported.

Therefore, **the pattern is always case-sensitive** and `[a-zA-Z]*` (i.e. making the regex itself explicitly case insensitive) is the only way to match the pattern in a case-insensitive way.

Comment: @dominicbri7 "with [...] flags ***disabled***". If the flag to ignore case is disabled, then it doesn't ignore case, so it's case sensitive.

Comment: so inconvenient when it comes to matching multiple terms in a case insensitive manner

Comment: [sS][uU][cC][kK][sS]\.

Comment: ...though I can't find where documentation claims they are disabled...

Comment: @massic80 The [HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#compiled-pattern-regular-expression) says the pattern is the result of `RegExpCreate(pattern, "v")`, and [the ES spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-regexpcreate) states that `v` is the UnicodeSets flag. To be case-*in*sensitive, it would have to be created with the `i` flag, too.