# HTML 5 Input regex pattern not working

Tags: javascript, regex, html

For some reason I'm having problems making this work with HTML5 form validation pattern attribute. I'm trying to match this condition `/[!?^$\\\/{}]/g`.  I have tried escaping `\` removing the `\` with the global attribute, removing the `[]`, almost everything.  So there's always a first time to post a question on stackoverflow.

In a nutshell the user shouldn't input the following `\/${}`

```
<form action="#">
    <input type="text" required pattern="/[!?^$\\\/{}]/g">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

`4.20 - 4.21 New export` -> Should be valid

`4/20 - 2/21 $New {export}` -> Should be invalid

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TV28A/

Comment: What strings are you validating this regex against?

Comment: I don't think you can use the /.../g format [SO - Click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524842/have-html5s-a-inputs-pattern-attribute-ignore-case)

Comment: You mean as an example?  If the user does `4/20 - 4/21 $Date`  That should be rejected.  It should accept all string characters except  `\/${}` @GregBurghardt

Comment: @JasonWilczak tried that already and it didn't worked

Comment: can you provide an example of a string that you want to to be considered valid and one that you don't?

Comment: @JasonWilczak  I added it in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried all the answers above and any worked *(don't know if I am testing wrong)*. But Just in case:

I think if you want to block only the `\/${}` characters, this should be the right regex `[^\/\\${}]*`

so the code would be something like:

```
<form action="#">
    <input type="text" required pattern="[^\/\\${}]*">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Putting the `^` character as the first one into the brackets, it negate the sentence, so `[^\/\\${}]*` means string which do **NOT** have `/ \ $ { }` of any size.

**EDIT:**

Sharing the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p77qs/) as requested in the comments.

Comment: Can you show a jsFiddle where this works.  I can't get it to work.

Comment: posted jsFiddle as requested @jfriend00

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for you to enclose your RegEx in `/` when using the `pattern` attribute. Furthermore, the `g` flag is also unnecessary due to the fact that the expression must match the entire input field, rather than just a section of it.

This should suffice for your purposes:

```
<form action="#">
  <input type="text" required pattern="[!?^$\\\/{}]">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Did you guys try this with the jsfiddle link?  Doesn't seem to be working.  cc: @jfriend00

Comment: this doesn't validate OP's strings as desired [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jasonwilczak/TV28A/4/)

Comment: @JasonWilczak  I must be going crazy but your Fiddle is not working for me.

Comment: Yeah, my point was to show that the answer wasn't working based on the Fiddle i provided, sorry about that :)