# Angular2 - Why does my reactive form input with an html pattern attribute is not validating correctly?

Tags: regex, angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I'm struggling with a problem that I can't understand:

I need to validate an input field with a `pattern="[0-9]+([,.][0-9])?"` attribute on an **angular reactive form** with `Validators.pattern`, but it seems my `?` quantifier at the end is not working...

**What I want**

I want to validate numbers with zero or one decimal maximum. As you can see on https://regex101.com/r/2D2sww/1, the regex is working great.

**The actual problem**

In my app I can enter as many decimals as I want without the `Validator.pattern` to do anything. Any other character invalidate the form, so **my Validator is working**.

Here is my code (simplified):

**component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
<input type="number" formControlName="myInputField" id="myInputField" pattern="[0-9]+([,.][0-9])?" required />
</form>
```

**component.ts** (Every import and declarations are skipped for clarity)

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      myInputField: [
          "",
          [Validators.required, Validators.pattern],
      ]
  });
}
```

I already tried to use `Validators.pattern(/^[0-9]+([,.][0-9])?$/)` and `Validators.pattern("[0-9]+([,.][0-9])?")` as pointed [in the documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#pattern), but it doesn't change anything, so I suspect my Regex to be incorrect...

Any ideas ? Thanks, have a nice day :)

Comment: You [should not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23433521/3832970) use the regex delimiters in a string regex pattern. `pattern="/^[0-9]+([,.][0-9])?$/"` => `pattern="^[0-9]+([,.][0-9])?$"` and even `pattern="[0-9]+([,.][0-9])?"`. Then, it is a *on-submit* validation, not *live* validation. When the user submits the data, validation will trigger.

Comment: @wiktor-stribiżew I thought the second part of your comment was the key, as I already tried the first part (see the end of my question), but nope, Validators in angular reactive forms are live, not on submit. When I enter a letter in my fields, the Validator is working and sending an alert. So as I said, it's only the second part of my regex that is not working.
Could you please re-open this question as it's not a duplicate? :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is nothing wrong with your validator pattern regex, 
you can remove the `pattern`'s attribute from the input, it is redundant because you are initiating it from inside the ts file: `'myInputField': new FormControl(null, [Validators.pattern('^[0-9]+([,.][0-9])?$')])`.

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/61231382-6844481)

Comment: Well, I don't know what to say, this morning I tried again, I removed the input attribute and everything is working well...

However, I tried to add back the input attribute to see if that was really the problem, and it's working...

So yeah, there was nothing wrong, that was a magical error I guess, disturbing me for two consecutive days ;)

Thank you for your trouble, I mark your answer as correct (as it it, nothing was wrong), even if the mystery persists :)

Comment: I truly believe it is related to the duplicated pattern attribute