# HTML5 Input Pattern Case-Insensitivity

Tags: javascript, regex, html, input

I'm trying to create something right now and I need the `pattern` attribute that was introduced in [html5](/questions/tagged/html5) tp be case-insensitive but as far as I know, you can't have flags to do this.

There was a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524842/have-html5s-a-inputs-pattern-attribute-ignore-case) asked in 2011 where it was stated that input patterns are case-sensitive and I was hoping that this was changed since then. If not, I'd like to know if there is a way to get a pattern to become case-insensitive. I can't just use the basic `[a-zA-z]` because I need to match a four letter word so as an example, it would start off really long `(word)|(WORD)|(Word)|(wOrd)`... and so on.

Is there a way to get a case-insensitive pattern like this?

EDIT:

Appears I haven't been to specific in my details, I need a specific word, not just any 4 letter word.

Comment: `[a-zA-Z]{,4}` will match Word, WORD, Fred, Arry, and so on...

Comment: did u end up finding an answer to this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ok I think I figured out an easier way to do the pattern other than listing each combination.

As an example, I'll use the word, "five".

```
[fF][iI][vV][eE]
```

so

```
pattern="[fF][iI][vV][eE]"
```

Comment: is there still not a better way? i am trying to match ~250 words, so this method would at least double the size of the "pattern"

Comment: @oldboy In your case I'd have some JavaScript intercept the form submit and validate it within the script. The `pattern` attribute is still rather limited I'm afraid.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern

Comment: yeah, thats what i was using, but i wrote a script to generate the HTML pattern, so that i can scrap a bunch of JS that handled form validation, etc, and used the native browser validation in its stead

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
pattern="[A-Za-z]{4}"
```

For example:

```
<input type="text" name="username" required pattern="[A-Za-z]{4}" />
```

This input has to be filled up with four case-insensitive `alpha` characters.

**Update:** You didn't respond which specific words you want to match but you can do it like:

```
pattern="word|WORD|Word|wORD"
```

So, for example:

```
<input type="text" name="username" required pattern="word|WORD|Word|wORD" />
```

Find more variations if needed.

Comment: Sorry, should have been more specific. I'll edit the question but it has to be more specific. The actual word.

Comment: Explain what is that ? Which specific words ?

Comment: What word doesn't matter. It's just 1 four letter word.

Comment: is there any way (via a tag like `/pattern/i`, etc) to match any case of a pattern like the following pattern? `option1|option2|option3|...` -- i plan to include about 250 options, so using an HTML `pattern` that includes specified options (instead of the whole alphabet) is really only practical if there is some way to incorporate a case-insensitive tag

Comment: What about `[A-Za-z0-9]*` zero or more alphanum chars.

Comment: sorry, what i meant was that i will be matching ~250 specific words, so is there a way to use flags in the HTML pattern regex (e.g. `g`, `i`, etc), so that the match is not case-sensitive (e.g. something like `pattern='/.../i'`)?