# How to set RegEx global flag in HTML pattern attribute of the input element?

Tags: html, regex

I want to client validate a form input (username + password) before sending it to the server (php).
Therefore I applied the pattern attribute in the input tag.
I came up with a RegEx expression that does the job on the server side:

```
(preg_match_all('/^[a-zA-Z0-9. _äöüßÄÖÜ@-]{1,50}$/', $_POST['username']) == 0)
```

thereby the global flag is set using preg_match_all (instead of preg_match).

Now I wanted to implement the same RegEx in my pattern attribute in the HTML form.
[HTML standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#the-pattern-attribute) defines that RegEx in the pattern attribute follows RegEx in [JavaScript](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-regexp-pattern-flags), which devides the expression into "pattern, flags" divided by a comma. I would translate that into HTML like this:

```
pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9. _äöüßÄÖÜ@-]{1,50}$,g"
```

That doesn't work.

All JavaScript RegEx validators I have found enclose the pattern into slashes:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9. _äöüßÄÖÜ@-]{1,50}$/
```

and say, that the global flag would be behind the last slash:

```
pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9. _äöüßÄÖÜ@-]{1,50}$/g"
```

That doesn't work either.

[Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdefpattern) also states in their developer guide (I also read it elsewhere):

> No forward slashes should be specified around the pattern text.

So, how can I get the global flag into the pattern attribute of the input element?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of facts you should be aware when using `pattern` attribute regex:

- There is no need to use `g` flag, the whole string must match the regex, and the regex check will only be performed once, a single match is enough
- There is no need wrapping the pattern with regex delimiters, and if you add slashes at the start and end, they will be treated as literal slashes making part of the regex pattern, and in 99.9% of cases that would ruin the regex
- You do not even need `^` and `$` anchors as the `pattern` regex must match the entire string input. In fact, the pattern is [automatically enclosed](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#attr-input-pattern) with `^(?:` and `)$`, so if you use `pattern="^\d+$"` (just a quick example), the final regex (in Chrome, e.g.) will look like `/^(?:^\d+$)$/u`, which looks rather redundant.

So, all you need is

```html
pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9. _äöüßÄÖÜ@-]{1,50}"
// Or even
pattern="^[\w. äöüßÄÖÜ@-]{1,50}"
```

Note that `[A-Za-z0-9_]` = `\w` in JavaScript regex.

Comment: Based on Wiktors hint regarding "\w" I used pattern="\w[\w. äöüßÄÖÜ@-]{0,49}" for username to avoid using a blank only as username. I also omitted "^" as start parameter, which worked perfect.

Comment: What about if you want to use the `u` flag to accept korean letters for example? ChatGPT told me that yes I can use a pattern like `/\p{L}/u`, notice the forward slashed. SO, chatGPT is wrong? At this time, abril 2023, shall you have an updated answer, please?

Comment: @limakid It is not important what ChatGPT tells you until you can explain to the minute detail what you are trying to achieve. If you need to validate a string that only consists of Unicode letters, you need a `^\p{L}+$` pattern compiled with the `u` flag provided the compiled regex is ECMAScript 2018+ compliant. So, if you need a regex that will work in a HTML `pattern` attribute, you can use `pattern="\p{L}+"` or `pattern="\p{L}*"` that will only work in Chrome, Firefox, Opera and other modern browsers that support that standard. It won't work in Safari.

Comment: Slightly related, how to set a flag like `i` (case insensitive)? I've tried `pattern="(?i)mypattern"` but Firefox complains the following in the console: `Unable to check <input pattern='(?i)mypattern'> because the pattern is not a valid regexp: invalid regexp group`

Comment: @Gruber See [Have HTML5's a inputs pattern attribute ignore case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5525111/3832970). TLDR: It is not possible. Use workarounds, see [HTML5 Input Pattern Case-Insensitivity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23852036/3832970).

Comment: Thank you for the links! my google foo badly failed this time; that's unfortunate, when dealing with ascii the range fix is easy but dealing with latin languages letters with accents and so on it's a bit messy...