# Regex - how can I make my expression case insensitive?

Tags: regex, html, case-insensitive

Here's the regex I'm using:

```
.*?\@(?!yahoo|gmail|hotmail).*
```

Basically I'm trying to get all non-yahoo/gmail/hotmail email addresses. The above works, however if someone types "ISHOUTATEVERYONE@YAHOO.COM" then it won't match.

I've tried searching around for an answer but nothing working. Is this possible?

I'm trying to use this on a HTML5 Input Pattern attribute:

`<input type="email" pattern=".*?\@(?!yahoo|gmail|hotmail).*" title="Email Address (no yahoo, gmail or hotmail)" id="emailaddress" name="emailaddress" required="">`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Have HTML5's a inputs pattern attribute ignore case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524842/have-html5s-a-inputs-pattern-attribute-ignore-case)

Comment: @AndrewArnold I don't think so, I'm not using a pattern...

Comment: You certainly are using a pattern.

Comment: You'll have to use `[yY][aA][hH]...` in your pattern, for every alphabet

Comment: That's an idea that'll work @hjpotter92 :)

Comment: Since your check is a little complex, I suggest to delegate this task to javascript that offers a less fastidious way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.*?\@(?![yY][aA][hH][oO][oO]|[gG][mM][aA][iI][lL]|[hH][oO][tT][mM][aA][iI][lL]).*`

Thanks to @hjpotter92