# Regex to match first character and no more than 2 identical consecutives

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, html

I'm using jQuery to add a pattern attribute to a text field based on a letter I select from an array. I'm trying to restrict the values that text field can accept with a regex, but it doesn't work properly.

What I want is that the first char of the value must be the letter I choose of the array, and then don't accept more than 2 identical consecutive caracters.

My regex is this:

```
^["+letter+"](?!(.)\1).{2}.*
```

And it seems to work when I'm testing it in regexr.com, but when I test it in my page, just the part of match the 1st char works, and the rest don't. When I type something like "Aaaaron", the message of "invalid entry" doesn't show.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe it works at an online regex tester because you enabled `/i` flag?

Answer (score 1):

## Description

```
^(.)(?!\1{2})
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This regex will do the following:

- capture the first character
- validate the first character is then not repeated 2 more times. If two more of the same character are present after the first occurrence, then you have 3 of the same characters in a row.

Note to make this expression view upper and lower case versions of a letter  as the same character you'll need to use the case insensitive flag.

## Live Example

https://regex101.com/r/xG9mE9/2

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of a "line"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .                        any character except \n
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \1{2}                    what was matched by capture \1 (2 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

try this regex: (with letter being 'a')

```
$("form").find("input[type=text]").attr("pattern", "(?=[Aa])(?!.*(.)\\1\\1).*");
```

it validates the starting letter, and that no character appears more than 2 times consecutively:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ex4zc8ga/1/)

notes:

- you [can't do case insensitive matching](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5525111/244811) with HTML5 pattern attribute, so 'a' and 'A' are not the same thing ('Aaaron' isn't 3 a's in a row)
- if adding pattern via a string (not a regex literal) in jquery/javascript, remember there's string interpolation first and then regex interpolation second (the backslash means something to String as well to Regex, you might need to double escape them: (`\\1` for a backreference in this case)
- you don't need `^` or `$` to make the input value match the entire pattern only, the regex is wrapped in `^(?:regex)$` for you. This means that if your pattern does not *consume* the entire string it will not work: `(?=[Aa])(?!.*(.)\\1\\1)`, which are just a couple of lookarounds, and would normally validate the input just fine, is a zero-width pattern, and without the `.*` at the end, does not work.

Comment: Still not showing the message of invalid entry, but this seems to be the right regex. Do you know what could be the cause? I'm using the HTML5+CSS3 validator (input:valid, input:invalid), but the message only shows when I type a wrong letter at first, but not when I type consecutive identicals.

Comment: can you create a https://jsfiddle.net/ illustrating the bug? (you can add jquery as external lib)

Comment: Now the message is displayed even if I type a valid string :(

Comment: got it. you need to double escape the backreferences `\\1` to allow them to get through the string processing and the regex processing.