# CustomValidator not calling javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am trying customvalidator control of asp.net but the problem is that it is not calling the javascript function. However it is calling the server side version of the validation method..

```
          <asp:CustomValidator  EnableClientScript="true"  
                ID="RegularExpressionValidatorFixedNames" runat="server"  ControlToValidate="TextBoxChapterName" 
                Text="Name not allowed" Font-Size="XX-Small"
                ValidationGroup="Name" 
                ClientValidationFunction="LQA_Validate"
                onservervalidate="RegularExpressionValidatorFixedNames_ServerValidate">   </asp:CustomValidator>
```

the javascript function

```
         function LQA_Validate(sender, args) {
        var re = /(?! My Ls|My As|My Qs).*/ig;
        args.IsValid = re.test(args);
    }
```

the server side method

```
          protected void RegularExpressionValidatorFixedNames_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(?!My Ls|My Qs|My As).*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    args.IsValid = regex.IsMatch(args.Value);
}
```

what can be the problem is this problem because of the regex or I am doing some technical mistake?

Comment: I used console.log but the javascript function is called at all..

Comment: what it (console) gives any error like _function undefined_?

Comment: sorry I made mistake in comment it is called

Comment: I think some problem with the regex

Comment: What is the `args` variable? The `.text()` method expects a string, but if its a string primitive you can't assign an `.IsValid` property to it.

Comment: are my both regex validating the same ..

Comment: The two regexes are _not_ the same. One is matching a pattern against the start of the string (using `^`) and the other is not.

Comment: <span id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolderBody_RegularExpressionValidatorFixedNames" style="color:Red;font-size:XX-Small;visibility:hidden;">Name not allowed</span>

Comment: @nnnnnn I tried that ^ in javascript but was not working either.

Comment: The JS expression also has an extra space at the beginning. Either way we have no way to tell you whether the regexes are "correct" because we don't know what they're supposed to do. Again, what is the `args` variable? Use `console.log(sender)` and `console.log(args)` inside your JS function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641236/make-regular-expression-case-insensitive-in-asp-net-regularexpressionvalidator   I saw it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
 function LQA_Validate(sender, args) {
    var re = /(?! My Ls|My As|My Qs).*/ig;
    args.IsValid = re.test(args);
}
```

In `re.test(args)` you should use `re.test(args.Value)`;

So the code must be:

```
 function LQA_Validate(sender, args) {
    var re = /(?! My Ls|My As|My Qs).*/ig;
    args.IsValid = re.test(args.Value);
}
```