# Case insensitive UK postcode regex

Tags: .net, regex, validation, case-insensitive, postal-code

I have the following regular expression for matching UK postcodes:

> GIR[ ]?0AA|((AB|AL|B|BA|BB|BD|BH|BL|BN|BR|BS|BT|CA|CB|CF|CH|CM|CO|CR|CT|CV|CW|DA|DD|DE|DG|DH|DL|DN|DT|DY|E|EC|EH|EN|EX|FK|FY|G|GL|GY|GU|HA|HD|HG|HP|HR|HS|HU|HX|IG|IM|IP|IV|JE|KA|KT|KW|KY|L|LA|LD|LE|LL|LN|LS|LU|M|ME|MK|ML|N|NE|NG|NN|NP|NR|NW|OL|OX|PA|PE|PH|PL|PO|PR|RG|RH|RM|S|SA|SE|SG|SK|SL|SM|SN|SO|SP|SR|SS|ST|SW|SY|TA|TD|TF|TN|TQ|TR|TS|TW|UB|W|WA|WC|WD|WF|WN|WR|WS|WV|YO|ZE)(\d[\dA-Z]?[ ]?\d[ABD-HJLN-UW-Z]{2}))|BFPO[ ]?\d{1,4}/gi

From what I understand I can add `/gi` to the end to make it match case insensitive however this doesn't seem to work at all? Can anyone see why?

Comment: What is your regex engine? Depending on which one you're using, using `/gi` might not work and instead `(?i)` at the start of the expression will make the expression case insensitive.

Comment: @Jerry .NET, this regex is fed to a `RegularExpressionValidator` control on an Asp.net page

Comment: You shouldn't need to add `g` - only `i` - but when you say "doesn't seem to work", what do you mean?

Comment: @AleksG `when you say "doesn't seem to work", what do you mean?` I mean it doesn't match UK postcodes when entered lower case. Uppercase is fine

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make regular expression case insensitive in ASP.NET RegularExpressionValidator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641236/make-regular-expression-case-insensitive-in-asp-net-regularexpressionvalidator)

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2641246/1578604).

Comment: @Jerry Initial testing with `(?i)` at the start of the expression seems to work flawlessly. I would add this as the answer

Comment: I know that I can use `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` however the system I'm building reads in different regexs per country where some actually require case sensitivity which would mean I would have to code specific logic to handle UK postcodes whereas I would prefer this all to be handled by the expression itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on which one you're using, using `/gi` might not work and instead `(?i)` at the start of the expression will make the expression case insensitive.

So, you'd use:

```
(?i)GIR[ ]?0AA|((AB|AL|B|BA|BB|BD|BH|BL|BN|BR|BS|BT|CA|CB|CF|CH|CM|CO|CR|CT|CV|CW|DA|DD|DE|DG|DH|DL|DN|DT|DY|E|EC|EH|EN|EX|FK|FY|G|GL|GY|GU|HA|HD|HG|HP|HR|HS|HU|HX|IG|IM|IP|IV|JE|KA|KT|KW|KY|L|LA|LD|LE|LL|LN|LS|LU|M|ME|MK|ML|N|NE|NG|NN|NP|NR|NW|OL|OX|PA|PE|PH|PL|PO|PR|RG|RH|RM|S|SA|SE|SG|SK|SL|SM|SN|SO|SP|SR|SS|ST|SW|SY|TA|TD|TF|TN|TQ|TR|TS|TW|UB|W|WA|WC|WD|WF|WN|WR|WS|WV|YO|ZE)(\d[\dA-Z]?[ ]?\d[ABD-HJLN-UW-Z]{2}))|BFPO[ ]?\d{1,4}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just uppercase your postcode string before putting it through your regex.
Also have a look at this [question on UK postcodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164979/uk-postcode-regex-comprehensive?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using .Net perhaps use RegexOptions.IgnoreCase when you construct? Taken from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/150646/Regular-Expression-for-UK-Post-Code-Lower-Case).

That page also has a link to [this expression](http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=1047) which might be worth trying.

Comment: I'd rather handle this via the expression itself but thanks all the same