# FormView not saving due to RegularExpressionValidator grouping issue in expression

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation, formview

I have the following regular expressions, used to pick up a specific domain name and email address type:

```
(?i:^domain\\[a-z0-9]+$)
(?i:([;]|^)([a-z0-9.]+@(dom\.net|part1\.part2\.uk))(?=[;]|$))
```

I'm using them in a pair of `RegularExpressionValidator` controls on an ASP.NET page to do the obvious.

The two expressions have been tested ([first](https://regex101.com/r/JJfuoU/1), [second](https://regex101.com/r/k4xh3L/1)), and work fine. I've even tested them on regexstorm.net/tester, and they work fine there, too, or rather, it didn't complain at all.

I've tried entering data correctly and incorrectly into the text boxes, which does produce the desired result (i.e. showing and hiding the validator messages).

When I come to submit the changes for the data to be saved away, though, nothing happens.

[This thread](https://forums.asp.net/t/1857064.aspx?formview+not+updating+inserting) in the ASP.NET forums showed me that the issue could be related to an incorrectly defined expression. After testing and pulling the results from the developer tools with Chrome, sure enough I did find an exception listed, quoting an incorrect group expression (e.g:):

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: 
    /(?i:([;]|^)([a-z0-9.]+@(dom\.net|part1\.part2\.uk))(?=[;]|$))/: 
Invalid group
at new RegExp (<anonymous>)
at HTMLSpanElement.RegularExpressionValidatorEvaluateIsValid [as evaluationfunction] (ScriptResource.axd?d=nv7asgRUU0tRmHNR2D6t1I81CZYvhDRBNs2fZ336VJmjaWUtfpNHyosZQUxZ0B5WPXmV97rd4uGrASTweyiB-WOW1uyNsuPtZ3w36cKlE-LnO2_rZ0xo0PpdoCQY_z4Id3GA-_iewMRfjN0CNhHZOQ2&t=26028d1e:458)
at ValidatorValidate (ScriptResource.axd?d=nv7asgRUU0tRmHNR2D6t1I81CZYvhDRBNs2fZ336VJmjaWUtfpNHyosZQUxZ0B5WPXmV97rd4uGrASTweyiB-WOW1uyNsuPtZ3w36cKlE-LnO2_rZ0xo0PpdoCQY_z4Id3GA-_iewMRfjN0CNhHZOQ2&t=26028d1e:200)
at ValidatorOnChange (ScriptResource.axd?d=nv7asgRUU0tRmHNR2D6t1I81CZYvhDRBNs2fZ336VJmjaWUtfpNHyosZQUxZ0B5WPXmV97rd4uGrASTweyiB-WOW1uyNsuPtZ3w36cKlE-LnO2_rZ0xo0PpdoCQY_z4Id3GA-_iewMRfjN0CNhHZOQ2&t=26028d1e:162)
at HTMLInputElement.eval (eval at ValidatorHookupEvent (ScriptResource.axd?d=nv7asgRUU0tRmHNR2D6t1I81CZYvhDRBNs2fZ336VJmjaWUtfpNHyosZQUxZ0B5WPXmV97rd4uGrASTweyiB-WOW1uyNsuPtZ3w36cKlE-LnO2_rZ0xo0PpdoCQY_z4Id3GA-_iewMRfjN0CNhHZOQ2&t=26028d1e:90), <anonymous>:3:1)
```

Unfortunately, I simply don't know enough about regex to be able to figure out just where the expression is breaking down - I would really appreciate some pointers.

The ASP.NET page code for the related text boxes and validators...

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="labelDomainUsername" 
    Text="Your domain username..." AssociatedControlID="textDomainUsername" 
    ClientIDMode="Predictable" />
<span class="help">
    This is your Windows login, and usually appears as <strong>DOMAIN\asurname</strong>.
</span>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="textDomainUsername" 
    Text='<%# Bind("domain_username")%>' 
    CssClass="mandatory w2Eighths noBlock" 
    PlaceHolder="DOMAIN\AUsername" TabIndex="0" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ID="rexDomainUser"
    ControlToValidate="textDomainUsername" 
    ValidationExpression='<%$ appSettings:rexDomainAccount %>'
    Text="Please supply a valid domain username."
    CssClass="validBalloon" Display="Dynamic" />

<asp:Label runat="server" ID="labelEmail" 
    Text="Your email address..." AssociatedControlID="textEmail" />
<span class="help">
    Your email address can be an <strong>dom.net</strong> or <strong>part1.part2.uk</strong>
    account. If you have a secretary, or wish to include another email address separate them with a 
    semi-colon.
</span>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="textEmail" Text='<%# Bind("email")%>' 
    CssClass="mandatory w3Eighths noBlock" AutoCompleteType="Email" 
    PlaceHolder="any.username@dom.net" TabIndex="1" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ID="rexEmail"
    ControlToValidate="textEmail" 
    ValidationExpression='<%$ appSettings:rexEmailAddress %>'
    Text="Please supply a valid email address."
    CssClass="validBalloon" Display="Dynamic" />
```

Comment: You have backlashes in your regex. Are you escaping them or surrounding your string using `@` such as  `@"regexHere"` instead of `"regexHere"`

Comment: The backslashes are escaped. The single slashes are escaping the dot characters (`\.`), and the double slashes are escaping the slash `\\\`.

Comment: Can you post the code that runs the regex?

Comment: That's the ASP.NET stuff (there is no code behind).

Comment: Try using `/:([;]|^)([a-z0-9.]+@(dom\.net|part1\.part2\.uk))(?=[;]|$)/i` instead. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20325114/asp-net-validationexpression-to-ignore-case-sensitivity) shows a common issue with RegularExpressionValidator, although I'm not convinced it's your issue.

Comment: Thanks @ctwheels. I'll give it a go and let you know.

Comment: @ctwheels: Thanks for your help with this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out, there are certain issues with utilising the `RegularExpressionValidator`. There are multiple ways around the issue, but all I've done is replace it with a `CustomValidator` and validate the parts of the string that I needed too.

Comment: Ha! Ha! I was asked whether I was a bot or a human on posting this!  They must be messing with our network again. ;o)