# US State Regular expression with case sensitive

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC application, and my model has a regular expression to validate US states.

This regular expression works fine if the user enters all upper case, but it is not working for lower case/camel case scenarios.

```
[RegularExpression(@"^((A[ELKSZR])|(C[AOT])|(D[EC])|(F[ML])|(G[AU])|(HI)|(I[DLNA])|(K[SY])|(LA)|(M[EHDAINSOT])|(N[EVHJMYCD])|(MP)|(O[HKR])|(P[WAR])|(RI)|(S[CD])|(T[NX])|(UT)|(V[TIA])|(W[AVIY]))$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid State")]
public string State { get; set; }
```

I tried this one, but no luck.

```
[RegularExpression(@"^(?-i:A[LKSZRAEP]|C[AOT]|D[EC]|F[LM]|G[AU]|HI|I[ADLN]|K[SY]|LA|M[ADEHINOPST]|N[CDEHJMVY]|O[HKR]|P[ARW]|RI|S[CD]|T[NX]|UT|V[AIT]|W[AIVY])$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid State")]
```

How can I fix my regular expression to match a US state, regardless of case?

Comment: Is it for client side? If yes, you can't use `(?i)`. For server-side, you can use the `(?i)` modifier at the beginning of the pattern, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this expression can be used for client side validation (and thus requires ECMA regex syntax, that is, JavaScript-compatible regular expression) you cannot use an inline modifier like `(?i)` let alone the toggled version `(?i:...)`.

You have to double each letter with the lowercase counterpart:

```
^(([Aa][EeLlKkSsZzRr])|([Cc][AaOoTt])|([Dd][EeCc])|([Ff][MmLl])|([Gg][AaUu])|([Hh][Ii])|([Ii][DdLlNnAa])|([Kk][SsYy])|([Ll][Aa])|([Mm][EeHhDdAaIiNnSsOoTt])|([Nn][EeVvHhJjMmYyCcDd])|([Mm][Pp])|([Oo][HhKkRr])|([Pp][WwAaRr])|([Rr][Ii])|([Ss][CcDd])|([Tt][NnXx])|([Uu][Tt])|([Vv][TtIiAa])|([Ww][AaVvIiYy]))$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/jF6bE0/1)

Comment: Also, see more about case insensitive validation in ASP.NET [here](http://forums.asp.net/post/2248685.aspx) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15047806/3832970).

Answer (score 0):

The list above is not as exhaustive - it is missing some military abbreviations. Trust me - you do not want to receive the ire of patriotic families trying to send stuff to their loved ones in the military.

Same technique - I added a few more.

```js
^(([Aa][EeLlKkSsZzRr])|([Cc][AaOoTt])|([Dd][EeCc])|([Ff][MmLl])|([Gg][AaUu])|([Hh][Ii])|([Ii][DdLlNnAa])|([Kk][SsYy])|([Ll][Aa])|([Mm][EeHhDdAaIiNnSsOoTt])|([Nn][EeVvHhJjMmYyCcDd])|([Mm][Pp])|([Oo][HhKkRr])|([Pp][WwAaRr])|([Rr][Ii])|([Ss][CcDd])|([Tt][NnXx])|([Uu][Tt])|([Vv][TtIiAa])|([Ww][AaVvIiYy]))$
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used

`[^,]*[A-Z]{2}`

hopefully, it works for you.