# Altering Regex to allow apostrophe in email address

Tags: regex, vb.net, validation, webforms

At work, our current ValidationExpression looks horrible and very confusing for me. We are using the WebForms `<asp:RegularExpressionValidator>` user control which looks like this:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regEmail" runat="server" 
    ValidationGroup="EditEmails"
    Text="*" ErrorMessage="Invalid email address." 
    ControlToValidate="txtAdd" 
    Display="Dynamic" 
    ValidationExpression="^(([A-Za-z0-9]+_+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\-+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\.+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\++))*[A-Za-z0-9]+@((\w+\-+)|(\w+\.))*\w{1,63}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$"/>
```

I need to somehow alter this to allow apostrophes ( `'` ) inside an email because at the moment this expression is failing.

Example of an email that needs to pass this validation: `Test.O'neill@example.co.uk`

I am unsure what the expression does but I'm sure this could be made shorter (maybe not simpler but that does not matter as long as it works).

Anyone know of a better regular expression I could use which works against valid emails and takes this into consideration? Thank you!

EDIT: My question is different because the proposed duplicate question does not work for VB.Net RegularExpression Validator user control.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to validate an email address using a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression

Comment: Try [`^([a-z\d]+[_+.-])*[a-z\d']+@(\w+[.-])*\w{1,63}\.[a-z]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/CKffa0/1). It's **much** shorter than your current version and greatly simplifies it.

Comment: That possible duplication question refers to PHP and I think ASP.NET would vary slightly and not work, especially considering the length of it.

Comment: @ctwheels Thank you. I'll test that out now :) I was really hoping to find a far more simplified one because the old looks like a terrible hack job.

Comment: @Mayron no offense, but it is haha

Comment: @ctwheels no offense taken, it's not my code lol. I've only been asked to change it to provide apostrophe support. It hurts my eyes!

Comment: @ctwheels Ah, damn. Doesn't seem to be working in vb.net :(

Comment: @Mayron it should work in vb. Have you added the `i` flag (case-insensitive)? It's a regex option

Comment: @ctwheels Thanks! I followed this stackoverflow question to add that option: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641236/make-regular-expression-case-insensitive-in-asp-net-regularexpressionvalidator

and it worked!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/CKffa0/1)

```
^([a-z\d]+[_+.-])*[a-z\d']+@(\w+[.-])*\w{1,63}\.[a-z]+$
```

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `([a-z\d]+[_+.-])*` Capture the following any number of times

  - `[a-z\d]+` Match any ASCII letter or digit one or more times (also matches uppercase variants with `i` flag enabled)
  - `[_+.-]` Match any character in the set
- `[a-z\d']+` Match any ASCII letter, digit, or apostrophe one or more times
- `@` Match this literally
- `(\w+[.-])*` Capture the following any number of times

  - `\w+` Match any word character one or more times
  - `[.-]` Match any character in the set
- `\w{1,63}` Match any word character between one and 63 times
- `\.` Match a literaly dot `.`
- `[a-z]+` Match any ASCII letter one or more times
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line

To implement the above pattern in a case-insensitive manner, add the `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` flag. For more information [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641236/make-regular-expression-case-insensitive-in-asp-net-regularexpressionvalidator).

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the breakdown! Very useful. Much appreciated :)