# How to make a regex match case insensitive?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have following regular expression for [postal code of Canada](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postal_codes_in_Canada).

```
^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]{1}\d{1}[A-Z]{1} *\d{1}[A-Z]{1}\d{1}$
```

It is working fine but accepts only Capital letters. I want it work for both capital and small letters.

Comment: Just type in the lowercase letters or make your regex case-insensitive.

Comment: ^[A-Ya-y]{1}\d{1}[A-Z]{1} *\d{1}[A-Z]{1}\d{1}$

Comment: language is C# but your expression contains [A-Ya-y] which is not correct because canada post code can not contain  letters D, F, I, O, Q, or U

Comment: You should probably also allow - as the separator. It's not technically correct, but it's easy enough to change to a space if you care.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Case insensitive Regex without using RegexOptions enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439965/case-insensitive-regex-without-using-regexoptions-enumeration)

Answer (score 150, accepted):

Just use the option `IgnoreCase`, see [.NET regular Expression Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs.aspx)

So your regex creation could look like this

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]\d[A-Z] *\d[A-Z]\d$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

I removed also all your `{1}` because it is superfluous. Every item is per default matched once, no need to state this explicitly.

The other possibility would be to use inline modifiers, when you are not able to set it on the object.

```
^(?i)[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]\d[A-Z] *\d[A-Z]\d$
```