# Save Extension in Data base with .(Dot)

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I am getting extension name from user to save in db in Asp Form . How i can validate that user enter extension name with .(Dot) and without .(Dot) name generate Error.

Comment: you can ask user without dot and then add dot yourself? Please be aware that multiple file extensions such as `file.ext1.ext2` may cause you trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to validate the data as the user is entering it on the form, before submitting?  If so, you may be looking for a RegularExpressionValidator.  See:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahwtc9e(v=vs.71).aspx and http://asp.net-tutorials.com/validation/regular-expression-validator/ then use one of the Regular expressions that Webruster and Ahsan provided you.

Sample:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtExt" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" 
          id="rexDot" controltovalidate="txtExt" 
          validationexpression="^[.]([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$" 
          errormessage="Please enter a Dot!" />
```

Comment: exactly. @Joe by using REGEX i validate my text box string and i also use the same expression as you write in comment.. Thanks for it...

Answer (score 0):

By using RegEx I can do it.

```
Regex.Match("String to Compare" , @"^[.]([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$")
```

I get user input in  a string and compare it with this Validation using RegEx.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression to validate file formats for `.mp3` or `.MP3` or `.mpeg` or `.MPEG` or `.m3u` or `.M3U`

```
Re= /^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\\{2}\w+)\$?)(\\(\w[\w].*))+(.mp3|.MP3|.mpeg|.MPEG|.m3u|.M3U)$/;
```

Regular expression to validate file formats for `.doc` or `.docx`

```
Re= /^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\\{2}\w+)\$?)(\\(\w[\w].*))+(.doc|.docx|.DOC|.DOCX)$/;
```

Regular expression to validate file formats for `.txt` or `.TXT`

```
Re= /^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\\{2}\w+)\$?)(\\(\w[\w].*))+(.txt|.TXT)$/;
```

Regular expression to validate file formats for `.jpeg` or `.JPEG` or `.gif` or `.GIF` or `.png` or `.PNG`

```
Re= /^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\\{2}\w+)\$?)(\\(\w[\w].*))+(.jpeg|.JPEG|.gif|.GIF| .png|.PNG)$/;
```

Comment: Would be simpler to use a case-insensitive regex, and shorten the list of file extensions. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11965836/1677912).

Comment: will look into that link thanks for the sharing the info