# Regular expression list matching without case sensitivity

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to use a regex to determine if a user-supplied value exists in a list of approved values, *regardless of case*. Here is a pared-down example of the current JavaScript code, which works to match "JAN", "Jan", and "jan"–but does not match "jAN", "jAn", etc:

```
var validateValue = function(field, patternName){
    "use strict"; //let's avoid tom-foolery in this function
    var pattern="";

    switch(patternName)
    {
    case "MMM": //month names only
        pattern=/^JAN|Jan|jan*$/;
        break;
    // other cases  and default follow in real code
    }

    if ( (!field.value.length) || pattern.test(field.value) ){
        //we're good (the field is blank or passes the regular expression test); remove field's error message, enable the submit button
    }
    else {
        //problems; let's show the error message and put focus back on problem field, disable the submit button
    }
};
```

I tried `pattern=/^`**(?i)**`JAN|Jan|jan*$/;` based on what I learned from "[Case insensitive Regex without using RegexOptions enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2439965/1430996)", but that doesn't do the trick ("Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression...")

**What is the correct regular expression for evaluating if a value matches, case-insensitive, a list item?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `i` (case insensitive) modifier like so:

```
pattern = /^jan*$/i; // <-- it goes at the end
```

Another way to define regular expressions is with the `RegExp` object:

```
pattern = new RegExp("^jan*$", "i");
```

I find this form to be more readable.

---

Also keep in mind that `/^jan*$/i` will match things like:

```
JAN
jannnn
jannNN
jAn
```

I'm not sure if that is what you want.

---

If you just want to match a predefined set you could opt for a non-regular-expression solution:

```
function isMonth(value) {
    var months = "jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec".split("|");
    return months.indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
}
```

Comment: with the i on the end wouldn't he just need pattern=/^jan*$/i; ?

Comment: Hmm..just looking for JAN, FEB, MAR...etc. So current pattern will be `pattern=/^(?i)jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec*$/i;`?

Comment: based on `pattern=/^(?i)jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec*$/i;`, would "DeCxyz" be a match?

Comment: I don't think `DeCxyz`, but `DeCccccc` will.

Comment: Thanks for the non-regex alternative, Frits, but this function uses regex for other patterns (email, phone, name).

Comment: I would discourage overzealous use of regular expressions. Phonenumbers and names are very hard to regexp match. E-mail is possible but I wouldn't worry about it too much since it's so easy to come up with an email address that _looks_ valid but isn't. Regular expressions is not the holy grail for getting people to enter valid information.

Comment: Understood. The idea behind this function is to assist users to enter valid search criteria. It's not a security mechanism--we handle that in other ways--it's more of a convenience function. If a user outsmarts the regex, they're only wasting their own time.

Comment: Sure, but if it's just a filter it doesn't matter what the user enters so long as it doesn't break your queries. If a user enters "puppy" as a phone number I don't see why she couldn't.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use regular expression options, you can try this regex :

```
pattern = /^[Jj][Aa][Nn]$/
```