# Regular expression for word and character like ({}[]^) not allowed anywhere in string

Tags: c#, regex

I want regular expression for `time` word and `[]{}^` those string format not allowed in string.

Like,

```
testtime -> allowed
tim etest -> allowed
thetimetest -> allowed
the time test -> not allowed
test[my -> not allowed
my}test -> not allowed
test^time -> not allowed
```

I develop below regular expression for word not allowed in string. But they cant check with case sensitive in `c#`.

```
   ^((?!Time)[^[\]{}])*$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead like this:

```
^(?!.*time)[^.]*$
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/tA1pA9)

---

**EDIT:** As per update, you can use this regex:

```
^(?!.*\btime\b)[^.^\[\]{}]*$
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/eQ7pM5)

As for case insensitivity, you can either use the flag `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` or use `(?i)` in the regex as like such `(?i)^(?!.*\btime\b)[^.^\[\]{}]*$`

Comment: Hello, I edited my question, please check with this.

Comment: i want to used this regular expression in asp.net regular expression control '(?i)^(?!.*\btime\b)[^.^\[\]{}]*$' but they cant fire.

Comment: @JeetBhatt Here's a [demo](http://ideone.com/Rgmnug) with two of the strings to test. Only the first one is matching.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
^((?!time)[^.])*$
```

Though a couple `String.contains` combined with Boolean logic might be clearer and more performant.

Comment: Hello, I edited my question, please check with this.

Comment: @JeetBhatt, I am not sure what you wanted. This is case-sensitive. If you want case-insensitive, put `(?i)` at the beginning of the regex, per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439965/case-insensitive-regex-without-using-regexoptions-enumeration.

Comment: i used this, but still they not work in asp.net regular expression validation control.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want a string that doesn't contain `time` or `.`..The regex would be

```
^(?!.*time)(?!.*[.]).*$
```

Comment: Hello, I edited my question, please check with this.