# How to add case insensitive form field validation in C#?

Tags: c#, regex, validation

I'm trying to add validation to a form field so that if it contains a certain word, an error is displayed. At the moment I have this:

```
Validation.Add("field-1", Validator.Regex("^((?!TEST)(?!test).)*$", "Field may not contain 'test'"));
```

This works fine for "TEST" and "test", but won't prevent someone entering "tESt".

I've tried adding the case insensitive flag, but this made the regex stop working completely:

```
Validation.Add("field-1", Validator.Regex("/^((?!TEST)(?!test).)*$/i", "Field may not contain 'test'"));
```

I also read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439965/case-insensitive-regex-without-using-regexoptions-enumeration) that (?i) can be used to ignore case, but that didn't work either - maybe I'm putting it in the wrong place:

```
Validation.Add("field-1", Validator.Regex("^((?i)(?!TEST)(?!test).)*$", "Field may not contain 'test'"));
```

Is this doable without adding every possible variation of "test"?

Comment: Try `"(?i)^(?!.*TEST).*$"`. It also seems your [`"^((?i)(?!TEST)(?!test).)*$"`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%28%3fi%29%28%3f!TEST%29%28%3f!test%29.%29*%24&i=There+is+a+tESt+here) should also work (although a tempered greedy token here is an "overkill").

Comment: No luck with that. Seems like any variation of (?i) kills the whole thing.

Comment: Does it mean you run this on the client side? `(?i)` won't work in JS, it will only work in .NET (well, and in some other regex flavors).

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how this works, but it seems to be client side using both .NET and JS. The validation rule adds a bunch of data attributes to my form field, including this: `data-val-regex-pattern="(?i)^(?!.*TEST).*$"`. I don't know what's going on behind the scenes, but it seems like the JS part doesnt like (?i) and the .NET part doesnt like the /i flag.

Comment: Right, JS will never understand `(?i)`. You have to use `^(?!.*[Tt][Ee][sS][tT]).*$`

Comment: Thanks, you're a saint. Can't believe I didn't think of this. Can you post it as an answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Comment: Posted with some explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that that your regex is handled on the client side. JavaScript `RegExp` does not support `(?i)` inline modifier (it does not support any inline modifiers, even the `XRegExp` library), so the only way out is to spell out all the letter cases using character classes:

```
Validation.Add("field-1", Validator.Regex("^(?!.*[Tt][Ee][sS][tT]).*$", "Field may not contain 'test'"));
```

Note that your tempered greedy token is too resource consuming a pattern, it is easier to use a simple negative lookahead here. If you need to support multiline strings, replace the `.` with `[\s\S]` character class.

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*[Tt][Ee][sS][tT])` -  there cannot be any `Test` or `TesT`, etc., after any 0+ chars
- `.*` - any 0+ chars, as many as possible
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 4):

Use an instance of the [`Regex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5845fdz(v=vs.110).aspx) class with a `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` parameter.

```cs
Regex validator = new Regex(@"TEST", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

if(validator.IsMatch(formValue))
{
    // Do something about this
}
```